# Javascript how do you sort an array of objects at the top level by nested object property

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, dictionary, ecmascript-6

```
var originalArray = [
    {
        name: 'Store1',
        inventory: [
            { name: 'Oranges', qt: [{ id: "something", time: 11 }, { id: "something", time: 44 }, { id: "something", time: 53 }] },
            { name: 'Mango', qt: [{ id: "something", time: 3 }, { id: "something", time: 91 }, { id: "something", time: 3 }] },
            { name: 'Kiwi', qt: [{ id: "something", time: 2 }, { id: "something", time: 91 }, { id: "something", time: 3 }] },
            { name: 'Papaya', qt: [{ id: "something", time: 8 }, { id: "something", time: 91 }, { id: "something", time: 3 }] }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'Store2',
        inventory: [
            { name: 'Pizza', qt: [{ id: "something", time: 31 }, { id: "something", time: 11 }, { id: "something", time: 23 }] },
            { name: 'Burger', qt: [{ id: "something", time: 1 }, { id: "something", time: 11 }, { id: "something", time: 23 }] },
            { name: 'IceCream', qt: [{ id: "something", time: 111 }, { id: "something", time: 11 }, { id: "something", time: 323 }] }
        ]
    }
];
```

For example in the above array, `inventory` and `qt` are nested keys with an array of objects as their value.
`Store2` has `{ id: "something", time: 323 }` which is a higher time than any item in `Store1`
After sort, `Store2` will be first in the list and `Store1` will be in second position, and so on, time descending

My code is not working to sort the stores.
It should not sort the nested array in inventory & qt, just sort the Store order by time descending

```
const sorted = originalArray
  .map(store => store.inventory
  .map(inv => inv.qt
  .map(item => Object.entries(item)[1])))
  .sort((a, b) => b[1].time - a[1].time)
  .map(item => item[1])

console.log(JSON.stringify(sorted));
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
// sorted array
[
    {
        name: 'Store2',
        inventory: [
            { name: 'Pizza', qt: [{ id: "something", time: 31 }, { id: "something", time: 11 }, { id: "something", time: 23 }] },
            { name: 'Burger', qt: [{ id: "something", time: 1 }, { id: "something", time: 11 }, { id: "something", time: 23 }] },
            { name: 'IceCream', qt: [{ id: "something", time: 111 }, { id: "something", time: 11 }, { id: "something", time: 323 }] }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'Store1',
        inventory: [
            { name: 'Oranges', qt: [{ id: "something", time: 11 }, { id: "something", time: 44 }, { id: "something", time: 53 }] },
            { name: 'Mango', qt: [{ id: "something", time: 3 }, { id: "something", time: 91 }, { id: "something", time: 3 }] },
            { name: 'Kiwi', qt: [{ id: "something", time: 2 }, { id: "something", time: 91 }, { id: "something", time: 3 }] },
            { name: 'Papaya', qt: [{ id: "something", time: 8 }, { id: "something", time: 91 }, { id: "something", time: 3 }] }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: What exactly is the expected outcome for `sorted`? Notice that after the `map`, you have an array of arrays of arrays of arrays.

Comment: Are you sure you meant `Object.entries(item)[1]` instead of simply `item.time`?

Comment: @Bergi hi I've just added the expected output for the sorted array

Comment: "*sort the Store order by time descending*" - but by which time? Your first store has 12 times, your second store has 9 times. How do you want to choose the ones to compare?

Comment: each array will not have an equal number of objects, it has to choose all the times and get the maximum / highest time for each store & compare between stores

Comment: Well then you should write some code that gets the maximum. Your current approach doesn't do that. Btw, what was the idea behind the `map().sort().map()`, was that meant to be a Schwartzian transform?

Comment: thanks I missed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```js
const highestTime = (inventory) => {
  let max = 0;
  for (const item of inventory) {
    for (const obj of item.qt) {
      if (obj.time > max) max = obj.time;
    }
  }
  return max;
};

const sortedArray = originalArray.sort((a, b) => highestTime(b.inventory) - highestTime(a.inventory));
```

Comment: thanks i further used `return Math.max(..s.inventory.map(i => i.qt.map(j => j.time)).flat(Infinity))`. more concise

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the most efficient way, but it does the job

```js
var originalArray = [
    {
        name: 'Store1',
        inventory: [
            { name: 'Oranges', qt: [{ id: "something", time: 11 }, { id: "something", time: 44 }, { id: "something", time: 53 }] },
            { name: 'Mango', qt: [{ id: "something", time: 3 }, { id: "something", time: 91 }, { id: "something", time: 3 }] },
            { name: 'Kiwi', qt: [{ id: "something", time: 2 }, { id: "something", time: 91 }, { id: "something", time: 3 }] },
            { name: 'Papaya', qt: [{ id: "something", time: 8 }, { id: "something", time: 91 }, { id: "something", time: 3 }] }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'Store2',
        inventory: [
            { name: 'Pizza', qt: [{ id: "something", time: 31 }, { id: "something", time: 11 }, { id: "something", time: 23 }] },
            { name: 'Burger', qt: [{ id: "something", time: 1 }, { id: "something", time: 11 }, { id: "something", time: 23 }] },
            { name: 'IceCream', qt: [{ id: "something", time: 111 }, { id: "something", time: 11 }, { id: "something", time: 323 }] }
        ]
    }
];
const sorted = originalArray.slice().sort((a, b) => {
    maxA = Math.max(...a.inventory.flatMap(({qt})=>qt.map(({time})=>time)));
    maxB = Math.max(...b.inventory.flatMap(({qt})=>qt.map(({time})=>time)));
    return maxB-maxA
});
console.log(sorted);
```